# Connect to Databricks from python via managed identity

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azure-managed-identity, databricks-sql

I managed to connect to Databricks from python using the following code snippet:

```py
from databricks import sql

connection = sql.connect(
  server_hostname='<server-hostname>',
  http_path='<http-path>',
  access_token='<personal-access-token>')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM <database-name>.<table-name> LIMIT 2')

result = cursor.fetchall()

for row in result:
  print(row)

cursor.close()
```

This snippet is from the official [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html#language-Cluster) and as you can see, it requires `server_hostname`, `http_path` and `access_token`. My question here is, can I authenticate myself without the `access_token`? Maybe use a managed identity, since both technologies are from Microsoft?

Answer (score 3):

You can use AAD token instead of personal access token. The simplest way to generate it is to use [azure-identity library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/?view=azure-python) from Microsoft.

Here is an example of code to generate AAD token for service principal:

```py
from databricks import sql
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import os

tenant_id = '...'
client_id = '...'
client_secret = os.environ['SP_SECRET']
csc = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

# important!
dbx_scope = '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default'
# this will be used as access token
aad_token = csc.get_token(dbx_scope).token
```

It should be also possible to use managed identity for that - just use [ManagedIdentityCredential class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-python#get-token--scopes----kwargs-) instead.  I believe that you can also generate a user's AAD token with that library. If you don't want to have an additional dependency, you can generate it via REST APIs, like this [code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/databricks/hooks/databricks.py#L186).

The identity that will be used needs to be added into Azure Databricks workspace by administrator using the [corresponding REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-sp) or [Databricks Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/service_principal).  And also given permissions to access Databricks cluster or SQL Endpoint - that's also doable via REST API or Terraform.

One thing that needs to be taken into account is that AAD token expires (how fast - it depends on what you're using: service principal or managed identity), so you may need to re-create connection periodically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Alex. Is `dbx_scope` the scope from Databricks? Where can I find it?

Comment: yes, it's the scope. It's documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--get-an-azure-active-directory-access-token