# is it possible to connect sql server using object id from azure managed identity in data bricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-managed-identity

please can some one guide me how to Establish Connection to SQL server using manage identity in data bricks using manage identity object id

I am using following code
'''

```
from azure.core.exceptions import ClientAuthenticationError
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential


# Create a secret client using the DefaultAzureCredential
c_id =  DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id)
try:
    #https://database.windows.net/.default
    #bipp-training-server.database.windows.net/.default
    secret = c_id.get_token("https://database.windows.net/.default")
except ClientAuthenticationError as ex:
    print(ex.message)
```

'''
and I am getting DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect `azure managed identity` with azure Databricks

Follow this [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107940/connect-to-databricks-from-python-via-managed-identity) thread by `@Alex Ott`

***Sample code***

> ```
> from databricks import sql
>     from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
>     import os
>     tenant_id = 'enter_tenant_id'
>     client_id = 'enter_client_id'
>     client_secret = os.environ['SP_SECRET']
>     csc = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
>     scope = '2xxxxx/.default'
>     token = csc.get_token(dbx_scope).token
> ```

Refer this [**document**](https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal) for connecting SQL to azure Databricks

Comment: This sample code does not use a managed identity.

Answer (score 0):

Managed identity is associated with virtual machines, and as of right now Databricks doesn't support managed identities for Databricks clusters.  So the only choice is to use Service principal authentcation